# ggplot label positioning in grouped barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently got into `ggplot` after only having used `spplot` for a while now and really like it so far. However, I got stuck now with a minor issue supposedly.

I have a grouped barplot and want to put the value labels on top of each bar. But it is not centered on the single bars, but centered in the middle of each group. Tried fiddling around with `vjust`/`hjust`, but I think the problem lies somewhere else. Any hints?

Here some reproducible goody:

```
loocvRSQR_OK <- c(0.7611536,0.6945638,0.6886343,0.8015664,0.7593292)
loocvRSQR_IDW <- c(0.7328284,0.6480901,0.5107468,0.7894640,0.7495850)
kfoldRSQR_OK <- c(0.6403418,0.7132792,0.6318929,0.8363614,0.7875515)
kfoldRSQR_IDW <- c(0.5576863,0.5956204,0.4998972,0.8427054,0.7905995)
timestamp <- c("23.06.2009 23:00:00","24.06.2009 00:00:00","24.06.2009 01:00:00","24.06.2009 02:00:00","24.06.2009 03:00:00")
df <- data.frame(loocvRSQR_OK,loocvRSQR_IDW,kfoldRSQR_OK,kfoldRSQR_IDW,timestamp)

library(reshape)
dfm <- melt(df[,c('timestamp','loocvRSQR_OK','loocvRSQR_IDW', "kfoldRSQR_OK", "kfoldRSQR_IDW")],id.vars = 1)
dfm

valplot <- ggplot(dfm,aes(x = timestamp,y = value)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.0, 1.00)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable),position = "dodge", stat="identity", width=0.9) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#006D92', '#2EAAD4', '#9C30E4', '#B87AE1'), name="Foo bar") + xlab('Time') + ylab('Level of force') +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(value,digits=2)), vjust=0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9), color='black', size=3) +
  ggtitle("May the 4th be with you") + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))

valplot
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it appears like there needs to be some kind of grouping element (to know which way to dodge, maybe?). When setting `fill` inside the general aes, or using 'group=variable', I was able to dodge the text.

Comment: did yoy try `vjust=-2.5` (work around this value) and add `hjust`. It  should work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, move `fill = variable` into the call to `ggplot` and make a slight tweak to `vjust` -- `vjust = -0.25`:

```
valplot <- ggplot(dfm, aes(x = timestamp, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", width = 0.9) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#006D92", "#2EAAD4", "#9C30E4", "#B87AE1"), 
    name = "Foo bar"
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "May the 4th be with you",
    x = "Time",
    y = "Level of force"
  ) + 
  geom_text(
    aes(label = round(value, digits = 2)), 
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
    vjust = -0.25, color = "black", size = 3
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(lineheight = 0.8, face = "bold")
  )
```

Comment: I surely will mention stackoverflow in the preface of my phd thesis...thanks again!